# GLSL: Incompatible Types at Initialisation (and no available implicit conversion)

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm recieving the following error when compiling my GLSL shader:

```
 Incompatible types in initialization (and no available implicit conversion)
```

It occurs on line `94`:

```
 int shadowMap = lightToShadowMapMapping[i];
```

I'm guessing its an incorrect type somewhere, however it doesn't make sense as `lightToShadowMapMapping` is an int array and the `i` variable is an int as well.

Here is the full source:

```
    0   | #version 400
    1   | #define MAX_LIGHTS 10
    2   |
    3   | in vec3 lightIntensity;
    4   | in vec3 surfacePosition;
    5   | in vec4 eyeSpacePosition;
    6   | in vec3 normal;
    7   |
    8   | uniform int numLights;
    9   | uniform struct Light {
    10  |    vec4 position;
    11  |    vec3 intensities; //a.k.a the color of the light
    12  |    float attenuation;
    13  |    float ambientCoefficient;
    14  |    float coneAngle;
    15  |    vec3 direction;
    16  | } allLights[MAX_LIGHTS];
    17  |
    18  | uniform float materialShininess;
    19  | uniform vec3 materialSpecularColor;
    20  |
    21  | uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
    22  |
    23  | // shadows
    24  | in vec4[MAX_LIGHTS] shadowTextureCoordinates;
    25  | uniform sampler2D[MAX_LIGHTS] shadowMaps;
    26  | uniform int[MAX_LIGHTS] lightToShadowMapMapping;
    27  |
    28  | layout(location = 0) out vec4 finalColor;
    29  |
    30  | vec3 applyLight(Light light, vec3 surfaceColor, vec3 normal, vec3 surfacePosition, vec3 surfaceToCamera) {
    31  |     vec3 surfaceToLight;
    32  |     float attenuation = 1.0;
    33  |     if(light.position.w == 1) {
    34  |         // directional light
    35  |         surfaceToLight = normalize(light.direction);
    36  |     } else {
    37  |         // point light
    38  |         surfaceToLight = normalize(light.position.xyz - surfacePosition);
    39  |         float distanceToLight = length(light.position.xyz - surfacePosition);
    40  |         attenuation = 1.0 / (1.0 + light.attenuation * pow(distanceToLight, 2));
    41  |
    42  |         // cone restrictions
    43  |         if(light.coneAngle > 0.0) {
    44  |             float lightToSurfaceAngle = degrees(acos(dot(-surfaceToLight, normalize(light.direction))));
    45  |             if(lightToSurfaceAngle > light.coneAngle) {
    46  |                 attenuation = 0.0;
    47  |             }
    48  |         }
    49  |     }
    50  |
    51  |     // ambient
    52  |     vec3 ambient = light.ambientCoefficient * surfaceColor.rgb * light.intensities;
    53  |
    54  |     // diffuse
    55  |     float diffuseCoefficient = max(0.0, dot(normal, surfaceToLight));
    56  |     vec3 diffuse = diffuseCoefficient * surfaceColor.rgb * light.intensities;
    57  |
    58  |     // specular
    59  |     float specularCoefficient = 0.0;
    60  |     if(diffuseCoefficient > 0.0) {
    61  |         specularCoefficient = pow(max(0.0, dot(surfaceToCamera, reflect(-surfaceToLight, normal))), materialShininess);
    62  |     }
    63  |     vec3 specular = specularCoefficient * materialSpecularColor * light.intensities;
    64  |
    65  |     return ambient + attenuation * (diffuse + specular);
    66  | }
    67  | //#include "lighting/fog"
    68  | float sampleShadowMap(sampler2D shadowMap, vec2 coords, float compare) {
    69  |     return step(compare, texture(shadowMap, coords).r);
    70  | }
    71  |
    72  | float calculateShadow(sampler2D shadowMap, vec4 initialCoords) {
    73  |     vec3 coords = (initialCoords.xyz / initialCoords.w) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    74  |
    75  |     return sampleShadowMap(shadowMap, coords.xy, coords.z);
    76  | }
    77  |
    78  | in vec2 textureCoordinate;
    79  |
    80  | uniform sampler2D materialTexture;
    81  |
    82  | void main() {
    83  |     vec4 surfaceColor = texture(materialTexture, textureCoordinate);
    84  |     vec3 surfaceToCamera = normalize(cameraPosition - surfacePosition);
    85  |
    86  |     vec3 newNormal = normal;
    87  |     if(!gl_FrontFacing) {
    88  |         newNormal = -normal;
    89  |     }
    90  |
    91  |     vec3 linearColor = vec3(0);
    92  |     for(int i = 0; i < numLights; ++i) {
    93  |         vec3 shadowAmount = 1;
    94  |         int shadowMap = lightToShadowMapMapping[i];
    95  |         if(shadowMap != -1) {
    96  |             shadowAmount = calculateShadow(shadowMaps[shadowMap], shadowMapCoordinates[shadowMap]);
    97  |         }
    98  |
    99  |         linearColor += applyLight(allLights[i], surfaceColor.rgb, newNormal, surfacePosition, surfaceToCamera) * shadowAmount;
    100 |     }
    101 |
    102 |     vec3 gamma = vec3(1.0/2.2);
    103 |     finalColor = vec4(pow(linearColor, gamma), surfaceColor.a);
    104 |
    105 |     /*float fogCoordinate = abs(eyeSpacePosition.z / eyeSpacePosition.w);
    106 |     finalColor = mix(finalColor, fogParams.color, getFogFactor(fogParams, fogCoordinate));*/
    107 |
    108 |     /*if(!gl_FrontFacing) {
    109 |         finalColor = mix(vec4(1, 0, 0, 1), finalColor, 50);
    110 |     }*/
    111 | }
```

I usually don't like posting huge code samples for others to check, but in this case I have racked my brains and searched the net for a solution but I can't find it. Thanks very much if you can help!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `uniform int lightToShadowMapMapping[MAX_LIGHTS];` not `uniform int[MAX_LIGHTS] lightToShadowMapMapping;`?

Comment: I used to have it like `uniform int lightToShadowMapMapping[MAX_LIGHTS];` but I changed it. (the GLSL wiki page says both work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the line right above it:

```
 vec3 shadowAmount = 1;
```

change it to:

```
 vec3 shadowAmount = vec3(1.0);
```

Looks like your line numbering is off by one.

Otherwise try explicitly casting to int in case the compiler has a different bug.

```
 int shadowMap = (int)(lightToShadowMapMapping[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! That worked perfectly. I had to generate the line numbering myself because my shader is generated from a number of files and I forgot that line numbers start from 1 not 0